# Trouble with Future when update to r16761

Tags: mongodb, dart

i have developed a function using Mongo Dart and Future. When i execute it using the Dart SDK 0.2.9 it works with no exception.

```dart
import 'model.dart';
import 'dart:json';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

class LinkDAO {
  DbCollection _links;

  Future<List> getAllLinks(){
    var completer = new Completer<List>();
    Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dart-link");
    List linkList = new List();
    _links = db.collection("links");
    db.open().chain((c){
      return _links.find({}).each(
          (link){ 
            print("[${link['link']}]:[${link['readed']}]:[${link['title']}]");
            linkList.add(new Link(link['link'],link['title'],link['readed']));
            print('lenght ${linkList.length}'); 
          }).chain((link)=>completer.complete(linkList));
     }).then((dummy){
      db.close();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
}

void main(){
  Future<List> futureResult=new LinkDAO().getAllLinks();
  futureResult.then((result){
    print("final!!! -> ${result.length}");
  });
}
```

This is the *Link* class

```dart
library models;

class Link {
  String title;
  String link;
  bool readed;
  Link(this.title,this.link,this.readed);
}
```

After the update to the release 0.2.10 the same function generate this exception :

```
[assas]:[true]:[sasas]
lenght 1
[assas]:[true]:[sasas]
lenght 2
final!!! -> 2
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'handleException'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Closure: _FutureImpl@0x36924d72<T>(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic]
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1360:3)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1361:25)
#2      _FutureImpl._forwardException (bootstrap:935:27)
#3      _FutureImpl._forward (bootstrap:931:22)
#4      _FutureImpl.chain.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:903:15)
#5      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:840:19)
#6      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#7      _FutureImpl._setValue (bootstrap:862:14)
#8      _CompleterImpl.complete (bootstrap:949:26)
#9      Cursor._nextEach.<anonymous closure>         (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:112:30)
#10     _FutureImpl.then (bootstrap:792:16)
#11     Cursor._nextEach (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:109:22)
#12     Cursor._nextEach.<anonymous closure> (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:115:18)
#13     _FutureImpl.then (bootstrap:792:16)
#14     Cursor._nextEach (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:109:22)
#15     Cursor._nextEach.<anonymous closure> (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:115:18)
#16     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:840:19)
#17     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#18     _FutureImpl._setValue (bootstrap:862:14)
#19     _CompleterImpl.complete (bootstrap:949:26)
#20     Cursor.nextObject.<anonymous closure> (package:mongo_dart/src/database/cursor.dart:74:28)
#21     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:840:19)
#22     _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
#23     _FutureImpl._setValue (bootstrap:862:14)
#24     _CompleterImpl.complete (bootstrap:949:26)
#25     Connection._receiveData._receiveData (package:mongo_dart/src/database/connection.dart:84:27)
#26     _SocketBase._multiplex (dart:io-patch:410:26)
#27     _SocketBase._sendToEventHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch:512:20)
#28     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:40:92)
```

I think the problem is on the Mogo Dart library but i'm not sure. Someone can help me?

Comment: Can you post the code for `Link`?  Its clear from the `Receiver: null` that something is not being created correctly and it would be good to have a complete picture of the code.

Comment: Link() is the class that contains some methods  to operate on MongoDb including 'getAllLinks()'. It's a kind of DAO. This class is composed only of methods and no attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
chain((link)=>completer.complete(linkList));
```

`Future.chain` needs a transformation function that returns a `Future` but you pass it a function that returns `void` (`null`). `NoSuchMethodError` exception is thrown when an attempt to forward error into this `null` is made.

I think you need `then` here instead of `chain`.

Comment: Puttin `then` in place of `chain` a different exception is throw. This code:  `.then((dummy){
          db.close();
          completer.complete(linkList);
        });`   works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have all the information to answer your question (I wish you would provide *all* your code so that I can reconstruct the app locally and try to debug it), but I'll do my best.

I see an obvious problem: `getAllLinks()` returns a `Future<List>`. Yet, when you call it

```dart
Future<bool> futureResult=new Link().getAllLinks();
```

you seem to think you'll get a `bool` out of it. Obviously this code:

```dart
futureResult.then((result){
  print('final!!! ${result.length}');
});
```

makes little sense in a context where `result` is not an iterable. So clearly, I would fix that.

Are you working in checked mode? Are you using Dart Editor and is it giving you warnings in your code?

Comment: 'Future<bool>' is a misprint. I have updated the answer whit the class _Link_ and the complete code of the class _LinkDao_.

Comment: I'm working in checked mode with Dart Editor ( release 0.2.10_r16761 ).